# ErrorProvider working on one call but not another?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, error-handling

I'm using an ErrorProvider control in winforms project.  Its working for the most part (although a bit of a pain to use).

Now I have 2 controls which fire the same validator.  In the validator I look at each control and set the error if its wrong.  One call works, but the other doesn't.  How can this be?  No exception is thrown.

Code:

```
  if (endHour > 12)
  {
     if (endHour >= 24)
     {
         //Fails without error
         errorProvider1.SetError(lblEnd, "You cannot enter more than 24 hours in a day");  
     }
     else
     {
         txtEndHour.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
     }
  }
  else
  {
      errorProvider1.SetError(lblEnd, "");
  }

 if (endMin >= 60)
 {
     //Always works.
     errorProvider1.SetError(lblEnd, "You can't enter more than 60 minutes in an hour.");  
 }
 else
 {
    errorProvider1.SetError(lblEnd, "");
 }
```

Comment: Using both txtEndhour and lblEnd must be wrong.  Where in this code does it take care of dealing with two different controls?

Comment: @HansPassant -If you mean that I shouldn't validate one control only to show the validator on another, that's not true, I have it working in several places.  I have a silly logic error here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you call this code with endHour >= 24 but endMin < 60 you will fall allways to the final else which clears the errorProvider. 
You should separate the two validation (better) or put a return when you find the hour part to be invalid.

Comment: -Yeah, I'm stupid.  I went to all the trouble to post this, then went home and while I was eating dinner I went "OHHHHHHH!  That's the problem!".  Thanks, your absolutely right.

Comment: Yes this happens to me also. Sometimes it's better to take a break! :-)